# Sum Range with Multiple range condition

Tags: google-sheets

I have this data in 2 google sheet tables
First table :

| Product Group | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Group A | Product x |
| Group A | Product y |
| Group B | Product z |
| Group B | Product x |

Second Table :

| IV | Product | Revenue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IV-01 | Product x | 10$ | 1 Jan |
| IV-02 | Product y | 15$ | 2 Jan |
| IV-03 | Product z | 25$ | 5 Jan |

I need to sum value of my Revenue of Product Group A within Date Range 1-2 Jan. What formula should I do?
I have tried
=sumproduct(Table2!C1:C * Table2!B:B=filter(Table1!B:B,Table1!A:A = Product Group A) * Date range)
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help

```
=SUM(
  FILTER(
    F2:F4,
    VLOOKUP(E2:E4,{B2:B5,A2:A5},2,0)="Group A",
    G2:G4>=DATE(2021,1,1),
    G2:G4<=DATE(2021,1,2)
))
```

[image]

The approach is based on the next formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  VLOOKUP(E2:E4,{B2:B5,A2:A5},2,0)="Group A"
)
```

[image]